# Javascript in HTML does not execute

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Environment</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
document.bgColor="#222222";
document.fgColor="#11EE11";

document.writeln("Test Environment.");
document.writeln("Last Update: " + document.lastModified);

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;


function enterExpenses(){
    var _desc = window.prompt("What kind of expenses?");
    var _amount = window.prompt("Amount spent?");
    var _entry = {type:_desc amount:_amount date:today};

    document.writeln(_entry.date);
    document.writeln(_entry.type);
    document.writeln(_entry.amount);
}


</script>
<form>
<button onclick="enterExpenses()">Click me</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I hate to be the guy asking others to do my work but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I'm trying to learn javascipt and I've completed the codecademy course. Now I'm actually trying to work with it and put it to use and I can't figure out why my script is not executed.

Anyone's expertise I can borrow for a second?

Comment: what part isnt working? there may be a few things, for example `{type:_desc amount:_amount date:today}` should be `{"type" : _desc,  "amount" : _amount,  "date" : today}`

Comment: You should read up on how to use the browser's console to debug your code.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is because of a typo in this line

```
var _entry = {type:_desc amount:_amount date:today};
```

You should separate object properties by a comma

```
var _entry = {type:_desc, amount:_amount, date:today};
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside form [Muhammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393022/2870404), use this for your button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="enterExpenses()">Click me</button>
```

Not specifying the "type" attribute for buttons will make it a submit button, sending your form to the form's action page.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've helped me out but I've ran into a new problem. whether i use document.writeln or even use the \n in a string it won't continue on the next line. howcome?

 for instance:
`document.writeln(_entry.amount + '\n');`

Comment: this might be a cheat but... i used <br>... 
    document.writeln(_entry.date+"<br>");

Comment: Thanks alot ,that worked. is there a reason i should not let javascript throw out HTML commands? @ray

Comment: I think it is not forbidden to use html commands in javascript. You will actually use a lot of htmls in javascript as you learn more. I just thought it might be a cheat if you are practicing the difference between writeln() and write().

Comment: I get that write doesnt and writeln does produce a new line and that the browser doesn't see it in this way but it still happens. are there alternatives to document.write(ln) that do not rerender the entire page? how do i write to the existing page? thanks for your help btw

Comment: developers usually use jquery for this. plain javascript are rarely seen now.